# MySQL - Keep duplicates and order in WHERE IN query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large set of values like from table "table_name"

```
('12345','12345', '48373')
```

That list is in fact much larger. Around 20k.

Table is like this:

```
 **processid**     **desc**
 12345              name
 48373              name2
```

I want the result to be in order and keep the duplicates. When I query like this:

```
SELECT processid, desc FROM table_name WHERE processid IN ('12345','12345', '48373');
```

The result is:

```
12345   name
48373   name2
```

But I want:

```
12345   name
12345   name
48373   name2
```

Comment: Where are name and name2 coming from ?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have `group by processid, name` at the end ?

Comment: By the way you'd only need to specify '12345' once in the IN Clause. Naming in twice has no extra affect

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya updated the question.

Comment: @MattJameson the data is coming from an Excel table (we wont change that data) and it needs to be just in that order even with duplicates. We will put back it to Excel after query just in that order.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan we don't have. Even if we have it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you have to export your data from Excel? Did it ask you to name primary keys?

Comment: @MattJameson It is not up to me. It is up to another department that giving data to me.

Comment: btw `desc` is a reserved word for mysql so you need to escape it in backticks i think

Comment: @LelioFaieta it is just an example. In real table it is not desc.

Comment: if `SELECT processid, exampleCol FROM table_name WHERE processid = 12345` only brings back one row then my guess is that the duplicates have been lost in the export process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve the records in the order specified in your `IN` clause, you would need to move your `IN` criteria to a sub-select statement and use a `JOIN ON` of that result set to your main table.

To make it less confusing and a bit faster, use a temporary table to hold the values you are wanting to retrieve from the main table. Use an auto increment column to retain the desired ordering of the records.

### Example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4e6ab/2

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_ids (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    processid INT
);

INSERT INTO tmp_ids (processid)
VALUES 
    (12345),
    (12345),
    (48373);

SELECT
    m.processid,
    m.`desc`
FROM tmp_ids AS tmp
INNER JOIN main_table AS m
ON tmp.processid = m.processid
ORDER BY tmp.id ASC;

#optional drop the temporary table
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_ids;
```

**Result**

```
| processid |  desc |
|-----------|-------|
|     12345 |  name |
|     12345 |  name |
|     48373 | name2 |
```

---

**Why `WHERE IN` will not work**

As was mentioned, MySQL does not use the `WHERE` criteria to retain the desired order and will ignore duplicate evaluations it contains. This is because the `WHERE` criteria evaluates only as `true` or `false`, to determine which records from the table(s) to retrieve or affect. Matching only the rows specified in the `WHERE` conditions that evaluate to `true`.

`IN` specifically can be thought of as a condensed form of repeated `OR` conditions on the specified column.

Meaning your original query is expanded as; Find records in `table_name` that have a `processid` equal to 12345 OR 12345 OR 48373.

For example using the following table data

```
table_name

| id |
|----|
|   1|
|   1|
|   2|
|   1|
```

Using a query like

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE id IN(1, 3);
```

Which is expanded as; find records that have an `id` equal to 1 OR 3.

Results in the following record set

```
| id |
|----|
|   1|
|   1|
|   1|
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer for you is: **you can't have that results based in the where clause**.

Now let me explain why. The `WHERE` clause are a set of conditions to **FILTER** the data in your table it by no means add more data to your existing data. if you have 2 registries in your table and you can't add more than that on the result querying it (unless you use something like [Salman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87015/salman-a) showed you).

So if you table is just

```
 12345   name
 48373   name2
```

The results will be based only on those 2 rows. The `WHERE` clause will only check whether that condition evaluates to true or false so:

`processid IN ('12345','12345', '48373')` this will test against all values in the `processid` column like this row by row (roughly explaining):

- For the row (12345 name) is processid value inside the `IN` clause: TRUE
- For the row (48373 name2) is processid value inside the `IN` clause: TRUE

Then you have only the two rows as results.

Like I said before, without using some technique which actually add more rows into your result set (union all, CTE, or whatever) you can't have that result you want based on the number of times you add a condition in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

the workaround may be programmatically where you can keep an multidimensional array with key and values where key will be processid and value will be the counts (how many times you want to display the processid) .in the iteration of loop of query result, you can check the processid with the key of the array and can display by the value of array.

Hope this helps.